# Tooltip doesn't hide when parent element removed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm using boostrap tooltip in a ReactJS app and trying to delete the parent element then the tooltip does not disappear and it rather freeze and stay in the page till next refresh

```
$("table#bootstrap_git_demo").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9AX5/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("table#bootstrap_git_demo").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $(this).closest(' tooltip div class ').remove();
});
```

Comment: actually Im just just initializing the tooltip in index.html(ReactJS app) and deleting the element is done from ReactJs. So how to deal with the situation ?
********************************************************************
        $(function () {
             $(document).tooltip({
            selector:'[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
        });
         $(document).on('hover', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function() {
            $(this).tooltip()
            }); 
          });